# Rails HABTM fields_for – check if record with same name already exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, tagging, relationship, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a HABTM-relation between the models "Snippets" and "Tags". Currently, when i save a snippet with a few tags, every tag is saved as a new record.

Now i want to check if a tag with the same name already exists and if that´s the case, i don´t want a new record, only an entry in snippets_tags to the existing record.

How can i do this?

snippet.rb:

```
class Snippet < ActiveRecord::Base
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a.values.all?(&:blank?) }
  ...
end
```

_snippet.html.erb:

```
<% f.fields_for :tags do |tag_form| %>
  <span class="fields">
    <%= tag_form.text_field :name, :class => 'tag' %>
    <%= tag_form.hidden_field :_destroy %>
  </span>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I'm also stuck with this, expecting there should be an answer, but no vote, no favorite, and no answer (apart from one from the author himself) for 3.5 years!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i´m impatient… after a while i found a solution that works for me. I don´t know if this is the best way, but i want to show it though.

I had to modify the solution of Ryan Bates Railscast ["Auto-Complete Association"](http://railscasts.com/episodes/102-auto-complete-associations), which handles a belongs_to-association to get it working with HABTM.

In my snippet-form is a new text field named tag_names, which expects a comma-separated list of tags.

Like Ryan, i use a virtual attribute to get and set the tags. I think the rest is self-explanatory, so here´s the code.

View "_snippet.html.erb"

```
<div class="float tags">
  <%= f.label :tag_names, "Tags" %>
  <%= f.text_field :tag_names %>
</div>
```

Model "snippet.rb":

```
def tag_names
  # Get all related Tags as comma-separated list
  tag_list = []
  tags.each do |tag|
    tag_list << tag.name
  end
  tag_list.join(', ')
end

def tag_names=(names)
  # Delete tag-relations
  self.tags.delete_all

  # Split comma-separated list
  names = names.split(', ')

  # Run through each tag
  names.each do |name|
    tag = Tag.find_by_name(name)

    if tag
      # If the tag already exists, create only join-model
      self.tags << tag
    else
      # New tag, save it and create join-model
      tag = self.tags.new(:name => name)
      if tag.save
        self.tags << tag
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This is just the basic code, not very well tested and in need of improvement, but it seemingly works and i´m happy to have a solution!