# How do I update a collection of items with another collection of items?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `Question` & `Tag` model. I would like to update the tags on an existing question, with a collection of tags in another collection.

This is the method on my `Question` model:

```
  def self.update_tags(tag_list)
    tags.each do |t|

    end
  end
```

I know I can do an each loop within an each loop, but that doesn't seem like the best approach (or even the most DRY/Ruby-esque).

Basically what I am trying to do is to update the tags on a question if they don't exist. So, in theory, I want to check each object in `tag_list` to see if it exists in `question.tags`. If it doesn't, then I want to push it. If it does, then ignore it and move to the next.

What's the most efficient approach?

**Edit 1**

I have a HABTM association between both the `Question` and `Tag` models.

**Edit 2**

I am aware that this is a classic N+1 query problem, so I am trying to figure out the best way to accomplish this in the most efficient way possible.

**Edit 3**

Here is an explanation of what is happening and the results I am trying to achieve - in an efficient way.

`tag_list` is being built like this:

```
tags.each do |tag|
    tag_list << Tag.where(:name => tag.name).first_or_create(:num_questions => tag.count)
end
```

`tags` is a collection of objects returned from a previous call to the external API.

I need to go through all the existing `question.tags` of the current question, and check it against the ids of the AR objects in `tag_list`.

Say a question previously had `tag_ids` of `[5, 7, 8, 10]`...what I want to happen is now with `tag_list = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`, I want to update `question.tag_ids = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`.

So, that would remove `tag_id=10`, and add `tag_id=[6, 9]`.

That's what I am trying to do.

Comment: its an n+1 query problem, you can use includes depending on your relation

Comment: I know about the n+1 query problem - that's why I am asking for the best way to approach it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails provides a native api for this called [replace](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb#L320)..

```
blog.tags.replace(tag_list)
```

**Old answer**

I would keep the logic simple. Internally, rails saves the association records in [one transaction](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb#L125). The performance of this and the hand-rolled multi-insert statement should be comparable. Also, using the rails layer insulates you against the intricacies of dealing with a new vs saved parent object.

```
def self.update_tags(tag_list)
  # Add new tags 
  current_tags = self.tags.dup
  new_tags = tag_list - current_tags
  tags.concat(new_tags) if new_tags.present?

  # Remove defunct tags 
  old_tags = current_tags - tag_list
  tags.delete(old_tags) if old_tags.present?      
end
```

Comment: I really like this, on the face of it....but will `concat` also delete elements in `self.tags` that don't exist in `tag_list` or will it just add tags that didn't exist? I want to update `self.tags`. In other words, if this question has tags removed, then I want them removed - is the end result I am trying to achieve.

Comment: This is perfect....works and is VERY elegant and simple. Thanks very much. This is EXACTLY what I was trying to achieve!

Comment: The `concat` adds the new tags. Since we calculate the delta in the prior step you should see only unique tags.

Comment: Right....but I want to remove items from the existing `self.tags`. In other words, if there are 5 records in `self.tags` but only 2 in `tag_list`, the end result should just show 2 tags for `self.tags` - which this doesn't do. This just adds the new records, but it doesn't delete records that shouldn't be there. So we are almost there and I love the simplicity and elegance of it - but how can we get it so that it also deletes tags in `self.tags` that are not in `tag_list`?

Comment: Updated my answer take a look.

Comment: I had to make another change to address a bug.

Comment: Updated the answer with a native rails based solution

Comment: Ahhh...perfect...that `replace` method is just what I need. Thanks!

Comment: Proper link to ``replace`` code: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb#L354

Answer (score 0):

May be you need `accepts_nested_attributes_for` ([docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html))

Comment: Not sure if I can do an `accepts_nested_attributes_for` with a HABTM on both sides? Don't see it mentioned in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

(**NOTE:** I did multiple updates, you are probably most interested in the code provided in **UPDATE 2** or **UPDATE 3**.)

I guess you can place the following in your Question model:

```
def diff_tags(other_q)
  other_q.tags - tags
end
def add_tags(other_q)
  tags << diff_tags(other_q)
end
```

Then doing the following:

```
q1 = Question.find(1)
q2 = Question.find(2)
q1.add_tags(q2)
```

leads to (Postgres in my case):

```
SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "questions_tags" ON "tags"."id" = "questions_tags"."tag_id" WHERE "questions_tags"."question_id" = ?  [["question_id", 2]]
SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "questions_tags" ON "tags"."id" = "questions_tags"."tag_id" WHERE "questions_tags"."question_id" = ?  [["question_id", 1]]
begin transaction
INSERT INTO "questions_tags" ("question_id", "tag_id") VALUES (1, <missing tag id 1>)
INSERT INTO "questions_tags" ("question_id", "tag_id") VALUES (1, <missing tag id 2>)
... and all other missing tags ...
commit transaction
```

You can further work on the queries to:

1) select only tag ids in the first 2 queries, not instantiate entire tags objects

2) INSERT multiple values in a single SQL statement like `INSERT INTO "questions_tags" ("question_id", "tag_id") VALUES ( <question_id>, <id1> ), ( <question_id>, <id2> )`, but you probably need using raw sql for that.

**UPDATE**: and here is the optimized version:

```
def diff_tags_ids(other_q)
  (other_q.tags.select(:id) - tags.select(:id)).map(&:id)
end
def add_tags_ids(tag_ids)
  query_head = 'INSERT INTO "questions_tags" ("question_id", "tag_id") VALUES '
  query_values = []
  tag_ids.each do |tag_id|
    query_values << "(#{self.id},#{tag_id})"
  end
  query = query_head + query_values.join(", ")
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
end
def add_tags_from(other_q)
  add_tags_ids( diff_tags_ids(other_q) )
end
```

Now the following

```
q1 = Question.find(1)
q2 = Question.find(2)
q1.add_tags_from(q2)
```

leads to just 3 queries:

```
SELECT id FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "questions_tags" ON "tags"."id" = "questions_tags"."tag_id" WHERE "questions_tags"."question_id" = ?  [["question_id", 3]]
SELECT id FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "questions_tags" ON "tags"."id" = "questions_tags"."tag_id" WHERE "questions_tags"."question_id" = ?  [["question_id", 1]]
INSERT INTO "questions_tags" ("question_id", "tag_id") VALUES (1,5), (1,6) # or whatever values are missing in question 1 compared to question 2
```

**UPDATE 2**: just realized that you don't need to read the tags from the 2nd question, you have them in tag_list already. Well, it's even more simple then:

```
def diff_tags_ids(tag_list)
  (tag_list - tags.select(:id)).map(&:id)
end
def add_tags_ids(tag_ids)
  query_head = 'INSERT INTO "questions_tags" ("question_id", "tag_id") VALUES '
  query_values = []
  tag_ids.each do |tag_id|
    query_values << "(#{self.id},#{tag_id})"
  end
  query = query_head + query_values.join(", ")
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
end
def update_tags(tag_list)
  add_tags_ids( diff_tags_ids(tag_list) )
end
```

This one I didn't try on the actual app, so sorry if there are some small typos.

**UPDATE 3:** and if you have tag *names*, not tag *objects* in your tag_list, then here's the update (assuming you have `name` attribute in your Tag model:

```
def diff_tags_names(tag_list)
  tag_list - tags.select(:name).map(&:name)
end
def find_tags_ids_by_names(tag_list)
  Tag.where( :name => tag_list ).select(:id).map(&:id)
  # That leads to SELECT "tags"."id" FROM "tags" WHERE "tags"."name" IN ('tag1', 'tag2', ...)
end
def add_tags_ids(tag_ids)
  query_head = 'INSERT INTO "questions_tags" ("question_id", "tag_id") VALUES '
  query_values = []
  tag_ids.each do |tag_id|
    query_values << "(#{self.id},#{tag_id})"
  end
  query = query_head + query_values.join(", ")
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
end
def update_tags(tag_list)
  tags_ids_to_add = find_tags_ids_by_names( diff_tags_names(tag_list) )
  add_tags_ids( tags_ids_to_add )
end
```

Still only two queries...

Comment: Hrmm....the problem with this approach is that it is focused on just creating new records in the `questions_tags` join table....which isn't the behavior I am looking for. So what is happening is, I am updating the questions in my DB from an external API. One such update may be a change to the existing `question.tags` of the current question. So, what I do is I check the new tags (and look for the local `tag_id`). Say a question previously had `tag_ids` of `[5, 7, 8, 10]`...what I want to happen is now with `tag_list = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`, I want to update `question.tag_ids = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`.

Comment: So, that would remove `tag_id=10`, and add `tag_id=[6, 9]`.

Comment: I have updated the question to show more details about what happens and the result I am looking for - building on my previous comments here.

Comment: Thanks for all the effort, but this answer is just too complicated for what I am trying to achieve. The selected is a better answer, because it is much more elegant and uses Rails native methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a tag is present inside the question with :

```
@question.tags.where(:id => tag_id).present? #check if the tag_id is inside the question.
```

but looking at your need it's :

```
def tag_names
  # Get all related Tags as comma-separated list
  tag_list = []
  tags.each do |tag|
    tag_list << tag.name
  end
  tag_list.join(', ')
end

def tag_names=(names)
  # Delete tag-relations
  self.tags.delete_all

  # Split comma-separated list
  names = names.split(', ')

  # Run through each tag
  names.each do |name|
    tag = Tag.find_by_name(name)

    if tag
      # If the tag already exists, create only join-model
      self.tags << tag
    else
      # New tag, save it and create join-model
      tag = self.tags.new(:name => name)
      if tag.save
        self.tags << tag
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Code pickup from here : [Rails HABTM fields_for – check if record with same name already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172551/rails-habtm-fields-for-check-if-record-with-same-name-already-exists)

Comment: I don't need a comma-separated list of tags. I already have the `updated_tags` in a collection called `tag_list << Tag.where(:name => tag.name).first_or_create(:num_questions => tag.count)`. So now `tag_list` is a collection of AR records. I like your suggestion about the `where` clause, which will help me determine if any of the elements in `tag_list` are in `question.tags`. The issue is, how do I handle elements in `tag_list` that don't exist and vice versa. I am going to update the question with a specific example of what I am trying to achieve.